# Update TextView in Android with amount of bluetooth devices found via ListAdapter or BluetoothAdapter

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, listadapter, settext

I want to create a `TextView` in an Android app which shows how many bluetooth devices are found and list them in the UI.

Inside the `MainActivity`(only acivity), there is an `ArrayList` inside a private class `ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter`. Besides in that class there is also a private `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` with `onLeScan` method that includes `ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. The `ListAdapter` uses a `listView` to bind the results of bluetooth scanning to the UI. The issue now is that I don't know how to create a trigger that sends the currently found/displayed (and constantly changing) amount of devices in a simple `TextView` above (!) the `ArrayList` and updates it every time the amount of devices in the list varies.

Do you have any suggestions? I have only found examples from different cases, and mostly with updating through buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should crate an `listener` for when a new Bluetooth scan is done. That `listener` should update the **UI**, `TextView`. [Read more about Android Callbacks here.](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners)

Comment: great article! Already build a solution drawing on the concepts described. Many thanks :)